# Partial Sudoku Verifier

Tags: javascript, array, html, css, sudoku

To practice my `JavaScript` for future employment, I've decided to take up the challenge of writing a javascript sudoku verifier. This code only verify's one of the nine 3x3 blocks there are. I would like feedback on this portion of the code, so I can continue my development with more knowledge and more efficient code. Also, any feedback on my `HTML/CSS` is warmly welcome. I'm using a fullscreen chrome browser for development, so the `#middle` centers the box on my screen, but it might not on yours.

**You will have to click on `full page ->` to view the `CSS` correctly.**

```js
function checkAnswer() {

 //reset each time button is clicked
 document.getElementById('correct').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('incorrect').style.display = 'none';

 //add each input into 2D array
 let first_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row1');
 let second_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row2');
 let third_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row3');
 let sudoku = [
  [first_row[0].value, first_row[1].value, first_row[2].value],
  [second_row[0].value, second_row[1].value, second_row[2].value],
  [third_row[0].value, third_row[1].value, third_row[2].value]
 ]

 //check if each number is unique in the 2D array
 for (let i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < sudoku[i].length; j++) {
   if(!isUnique(sudoku[i][j], sudoku)) {
    document.getElementById('incorrect').style.display = 'block';
    return;
   }
  }
 }
 document.getElementById('correct').style.display = 'block';
}

function isUnique(num, arr) {
 let count = 0;
 //check entire array
 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
   if(arr[i][j] == num) {
    count++;
   }
  }
 }
 return count == 1;
}
```

```css
body { 
 background-color: pink; 
}
input { 
 width: 50px; 
 height: 50px; 
 font-size: 20px; 
 text-align: center; 
}
button { 
 width: 100px; 
 height: 50px; 
 font-size: 15px; 
 margin-left: 40px; 
}

#middle { 
 margin-left: 900px; 
 margin-top: 300px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <title>Sudoku</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="middle">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="row1" maxlength="1" value="3"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row1" maxlength="1"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row1" maxlength="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="row2" maxlength="1"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row2" maxlength="1" value="2"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row2" maxlength="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text" class="row3" maxlength="1" value="7"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row3" maxlength="1"></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="row3" maxlength="1"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswer()">Check</button>
   <div id="incorrect" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Incorrect Entry!</h1>
   </div>
   <div id="correct" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Correct Entry!</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Styling

You can align centered elements relatively to their parent.

> ```
> #middle { 
>   margin-left: 900px; 
>   margin-top: 300px; 
> }
> ```

```
#middle {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

### Naming

In my opinion, for algorithms it is OK to use short variable names.

> ```
> let first_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row1');
> let second_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row2');
> let third_row = document.getElementsByClassName('row3');
> let sudoku = [
>   [first_row[0].value, first_row[1].value, first_row[2].value],
>   [second_row[0].value, second_row[1].value, second_row[2].value],
>   [third_row[0].value, third_row[1].value, third_row[2].value]
> ]
> ```

```
let r1 = document.getElementsByClassName('row1');
let r2 = document.getElementsByClassName('row2');
let r3 = document.getElementsByClassName('row3');
let sudoku = [
    [r1[0].value, r1[1].value, r1[2].value],
    [r2[0].value, r2[1].value, r2[2].value],
    [r3[0].value, r3[1].value, r3[2].value]
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to cut out the numbers completely from the variable names? Especially considering a full sudoku is 9x9.

Comment: @Mast In a more generalized sudoku solver, that would be my choice also.